# add a column to numpy array for groupby rolling count

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I want to add a column that will give running total by a group. I know how to do that in pandas( i.e cumcount +1 with groupby) but I want to move the data into numpy array and vectorize the operation. Example input data

[image]

Example output data with total # of complaints:

[image]

Comment: perform a `groupby.cumsum`

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have a equivalent to `groupby`